# ActiveRecord update error - illegal zero-length identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm running simple Rails + ActiveRecord program, where I want to take records from the database, where column "transfered_at" is null, and update it with the current time.

```
orders_ora = Orders.where(transfered_at: nil)
orders_ora.each do |order_ora|

   puts order_ora.name 
   order_ora.update(transfered_at: Time.now)
end
```

However, it does not allow me to do that. Here is the error that I'm getting:

> OCIError: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier: UPDATE
>   "ORDERS" SET "TRANSFERED_AT" = :a1 WHERE
>   "ORDERS"."" IS NULL (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

What am I missing?

Edit: I need to use this inside the loop because I'm doing other calculations inside it. And time format does not seems to be the problem, because I'm trying to update another column which type is "number", and I'm getting the same error.
If I try to do it like this:

```
   order_ora.inspection_id = 333
   order_ora.save
```

it also gives the same error as before.

Comment: use `Orders.where(transfered_at: nil).update_all(transfered_at: Time.now)` . Still if you have problem please let me know.

Comment: @kishorecheruku I need to use this update inside the loop, because I'm also doing other actions in it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `Orders.where("transfered_at = ?", nil)`. Just for verification use this code to find all orders. We need to find out why " illegal zero-length identifier" is coming.

Comment: After using the code you suggested, no orders are found at all, so there is nothing to do in the loop.

Comment: can you please use `update_attribute` instead of `update`.

Comment: @kishorecheruku I'm receiving the same error as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to this myself, it was not related to the code.

The problem was that **my table did not have a PK**, and it looks like ActiveRecords uses it to generate SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop through the results? You can do it in a single query:

```
Orders.where(transfered_at: nil).update(transfered_at: Time.now)
```

What could be a problem is that the Time.now is not in the correct format for your table? Use strftime in that case:

```
Orders.where(transfered_at: nil).update(transfered_at: Time.now.strftime('%H:%M') )
```

Comment: I'm looping through the results because I'm doing additional stuff with the selected order(taking its values into other variables). 

So, is there a way to update it inside the loop?

Comment: just tried to do this outside of the loop, sadly the error remains the same as it was.

Comment: DId you try the strftime method? It’s probably something in the DB level. Could you run a native query on your DB to see what happens then?